# Approximation ratio for covering n points in d dimensions

Tags: cg.comp-geom, approximation-algorithms, set-cover

What is best known approximation ratio for the following problem :

Given n points in d dimensions , what is the minimum number of axis parallel lines needed to cover them . A line is said to cover a point , if the point lies on the line .

Comment: A constant factor should follow from VC-dimension arguments. I assume you'd want a precise constant ?

Comment: Yes , I am looking for a precise value.

Comment: @SureshVenkat Can you elaborate?  I'm only aware of the log(OPT) approximation factor that would come automatically from VC-dimension arguments.

Comment: Each point is in exactly $d$ axis-parallel lines so this is a special case of set cover where an element is in at most $d$ sets. One can get a $d$-approximation via LP rounding but perhaps one can do better using the geometric structure?